# How to Count my pass fail test case and print at the end of execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, ranorex

I have multiple test cases and I want to write a common method which can count all fail or pass test case and print the total pass and fail test case at the end of execution.

Comment: public List<ClassProperty> GetUserDetails(int i)
        {
            ClassProperty userinfo = new ClassProperty();
            //userinfo.Name = i.ToString();
            userinfo.Pass = i;
           // userinfo.Fail = 1;
             classproperty.Add(userinfo);
          
            return classproperty;
        }

Comment: class ClassProperty
    {
        public int Pass { get; set; }
        public int Fail { get; set; }
        
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Class to count the total pass and fail cases, you can implement a method like this:

```
int pass=0;
int fail=0;
for(int i=0;i<testCasescount;i++)
{
  //read the input using Console.ReadLine();
  //check whether the test case is a pass or fail and appropriately increment the counter
}
//executed after the for loop i.e. all the test cases 
Console.WriteLine(pass);
Console.WriteLine(fail);
```

Comment: Actually I have multiple class because of multiple test cases so how I can count all pass and fail test cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
int Failed = 0;
int Passed = 0;
var TestCases = TestSuite.Current.SelectedRunConfig.GetActiveTestContainers();
        foreach(var testcase in TestCases){
        {if(testcase.IsTestCase){ //To Handle Smart Folders
                if(testcase.Status.ToString()=="Failed")
                    {
                    Failed++;
                    }
                Passed++;
            }
            }
        }
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Passed Count :"+Passed);
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Failed Count :"+Failed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 global parameters with value 0 (varSuccess, varFail).
Everytime you validate anything depending on the outcome just add to the either value. When test run has finished do what ever you want with those values (eg. write them to the report file, console etc).